# TaskListener is not working in ADF Project Gantt Chart..?

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper, facet, gantt-chart

I have a Project Gantt Chart in One Page with Tasks. Also I have added TaskListener to that. My requirement is When i click on the Task listener, It should go to the corresponding Task in the next page. Instead of that its  showing same Task(1st Task) eveytime in the next page.

My Bean Code :

```
public void doSelectTasks(TaskSelectionEvent taskSelectionEvent) {

    if (!queueActionOnCommandComponmentById(HIDDEN_NAV_BUTTON)) {
                _logger.severe("Error: unable to locate hidden havigation     component " + HIDDEN_NAV_BUTTON);
            }

        }
```

I have added a Hidden Button. to Navigate to the Next Page

My Gantt Chart Code :

```
    <dvt:projectGantt id="gantt1" value="#{bindings.JobsVO2.projectGanttModel}"
                    dataChangeListener="#      {bindings.JobsVO2.projectGanttModel.processDataChanged}" var="row"
                    startTime="1975-04-22" endTime="2015-07-21"     summary="Check"
   taskSelectionListener="#     {backingBeanScope.TaskSelectListener.doSelectTasks}" rowSelection="single">
    <f:facet name="major">
      <dvt:timeAxis scale="weeks" id="ta1"/>
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="minor">
      <dvt:timeAxis scale="days" id="ta2"/>
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="nodeStamp">
      <af:column sortProperty="#{bindings.JobsVO2.hints.JobId.name}"      sortable="false"
                 headerText="#{bindings.JobsVO2.hints.JobId.label}" id="c1">
        <af:outputText value="#{row.JobId}" shortDesc="#    {bindings.JobsVO2.hints.JobId.tooltip}" id="ot1"/>
      </af:column>
    </f:facet>
    <af:column sortProperty="#{bindings.JobsVO2.hints.JobTitle.name}"     sortable="false"
               headerText="#{bindings.JobsVO2.hints.JobTitle.label}"      id="c2">
      <af:outputText value="#{row.JobTitle}" shortDesc="#    {bindings.JobsVO2.hints.JobTitle.tooltip}" id="ot2"/>
    </af:column>
    <af:column sortProperty="#{bindings.JobsVO2.hints.MinSalary.name}"    sortable="false"
               headerText="#{bindings.JobsVO2.hints.MinSalary.label}"    id="c3">
           <af:outputText value="#{row.MinSalary}" shortDesc="#   {bindings.JobsVO2.hints.MinSalary.tooltip}" id="ot3">
        <af:convertNumber groupingUsed="false" pattern="#   {bindings.JobsVO2.hints.MinSalary.format}"/>
      </af:outputText>
    </af:column>
    <af:column sortProperty="#{bindings.JobsVO2.hints.MaxSalary.name}"    sortable="false"
               headerText="#{bindings.JobsVO2.hints.MaxSalary.label}"    id="c4">
      <af:outputText value="#{row.MaxSalary}" shortDesc="#   {bindings.JobsVO2.hints.MaxSalary.tooltip}" id="ot4">
        <af:convertNumber groupingUsed="false" pattern="#{bindings.JobsVO2.hints.MaxSalary.format}"/>
         </af:outputText>
    </af:column>
    <af:column sortProperty="#{bindings.JobsVO2.hints.StartDate.name}"     sortable="false"
               headerText="#{bindings.JobsVO2.hints.StartDate.label}"     id="c5">
          <af:outputText value="#{row.StartDate}" shortDesc="#   {bindings.JobsVO2.hints.StartDate.tooltip}" id="ot5">
        <af:convertDateTime pattern="#   {bindings.JobsVO2.hints.StartDate.format}"/>
      </af:outputText>
    </af:column>
    <af:column sortProperty="#{bindings.JobsVO2.hints.EndDate.name}"     sortable="false"
               headerText="#{bindings.JobsVO2.hints.EndDate.label}" id="c6">
         <af:outputText value="#{row.EndDate}" shortDesc="#   {bindings.JobsVO2.hints.EndDate.tooltip}" id="ot6">
           <af:convertDateTime pattern="#   {bindings.JobsVO2.hints.EndDate.format}"/>
      </af:outputText>
        </af:column>
      </dvt:projectGantt>
    <af:button text="Hidden Navigation" id="h_navb2" action="toF2"     visible="false"/>
```

Can somebody tell me where Im wrong and Is there anything else i have to do..?

Please help....

Comment: Have you tried printing out the selected task? Use:  System.out.println("Selected task details +taskSelectionEvent.getTask());

Comment: Yes, Its prints the task Im clicking-on. But in the next page its showing only the same task(1st task)... It prints the correct task Im clicking-on..

Comment: I guess you are also using JobsVO2 on your second page? Can you add the code of your second page and maybe a screenshot of your taskflow and pagedef to your post?

Comment: Im not able to attach Image.. Im using the same JobsVO2 in the next page. I have created a ControlFlow between two views in Taskflow definiftion...  Same iterator(JobVO2 Iterator) in both the pages...

Comment: Well, the problem is obvious. Your projectGantt doesn't set a current row or the current row is lost during navigation. A common issue is that you haven't defined a PK in your JobVO. If that is not the case you should try to figure where/why your current row doesn't get set.

Comment: There is a PK for JobsVO. Can you tell me in this Code, Where i have to set Currentrow.? Exactly next to what.? and If you have some sample code, is there please send it...

Comment: You could do it in your taskSelectionListener but setting the current row should happen by default.

Answer (score 0):

You need your selectionListener to fire a setCurrentRowWithKey operation so your second page will know which task to show.
This shows you the declarative way of using that method - you'll need to call that operation from your backing bean.
https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/selecting_a_row_in_a_table_to

Comment: Hi Shay Shmeltzer, There is no content in the Link you posted. Can you please help me with Fixing this issue. Still Im facing....